# Understanding generateTopKFrequentPatterns method of mahout FP growth algorithm in Java

Tags: apache, mahout

I'm new to Apache Mahout. I want to understand the method generateTopKFrequentPatterns() provided for Parallel Frequent Pattern Mining (from Apache Mahout) in Java.

The command line version of the algorithm provides two modes of running, sequential and mapreduce. Is the java method always runs on mapreduce? Or is it because, we are using outputcollector provided by mapreduce library?

How to run this algorithm on multiple hadoop clusters in a distributed way using the API?

The method definition is given as follows:

```
    generateTopKFrequentPatterns(Iterator<Pair<List<A>,Long>> transactionStream,
                                           Collection<Pair<A,Long>> frequencyList,
                                           long minSupport,
                                           int k,
                                           Collection<A> returnableFeatures,
                                           org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector<A,List<Pair<List<A>,Long>>> output,
                                           StatusUpdater updater)
                                    throws IOException
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
psun